# Network Card drive for Intel 1200v3RPS for Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop amd64

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, server, intel

I am configuring an custom built server with Intel Server Board 1200v3RPS. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop amd64 as the OS. Issue that I am facing in this is, On-board Network has not been installed by default.

I did a quick search and found that not many people have installed Ubuntu on this Intel board.

Intel website gives drivers for Redhat & SUSE only. This is first time I am installing Ubuntu on Server platform. So far only worked with Redhat/CentOS.

Kindly let me know how to do I install network card drivers in Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved, i used the driver from CD as it had source files. I used the below link as reference.

[Ubuntu 12.04 loses ethernet driver after update and reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385351/ubuntu-12-04-loses-ethernet-driver-after-update-and-reboot)

Inside the folder of linux drivers from Intel CD, I ran the following commands, and the network got connected.

```
sudo make install
sudo modprobe igb
```

Answer (score 0):

### ***Welcome to Ubuntu Linux***

You may not actually need a brand/device 'driver', as **Debian/Ubuntu** have generic drivers for most mainstream hardware.

**Unless you have a new chip/design, or specific high performance/availability requirements, the *standard* driver should suffice.**

*Gone and the bad old yesterdays (from RedHat/Fedora 4) of **insert first CD** (for OS install), then spend 20-40 minutes shuffling through discs 4 thru 9 for each brand/device driver. Ubuntu OS (and all drivers) has fit on a single 600MB CD until only quite recently.*

---

Does this have / need a screen, keyboard, and graphic interface?

*Otherwise you are better off using the **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server** variant.*

---

**UPDATE:**

Check (and or add to your question) output from **`dmesg | grep igb`**. *I'm not sure if that is the correct ID for **Intel Gigabit** Ethernet driver for Ubuntu, but its sound right.*

Look at [How do I enable the "backports" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25717/how-do-i-enable-the-backports-repository) for **Precise** (12.04) back ports.

Comment: Hi, The reason I used desktop edition here is, Server would be used for connecting nComputing clients of L300 model with vSpace software installed. So i need GUI. I know I can install Server and then configure GUI on but i avoided the two steps. Secondly standard/generic driver should suffice my needs here. But strangely Ubuntu is not loading it :(

Comment: Your *Intel Server board* has dual **Intel I210 PHY** (low power) Ethernet cards/chips. This is the same problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98417/cant-get-intel-i210-ethernet-working-on-debian-wheezy

Comment: Can you verify, with: **`lspci -nn | grep Eth`** ?

Comment: Yes as per m/b manual thats the dual NIC controller. I will reach office in couple of hours time and should be able to verify the command output. The stackexchange seems to give the solution need to check when I reach onsite. Thanks David.

Comment: Hi David, yes the the card is indeed Intel I210 PHY. as per the unixstack link, that was able to see the interface in ifconfig -a but in my case not able to get in ifconfig as well. Checking further.